# Simple publisher from Windows?

Tags: ros, windows, win-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a piece of hardware (a HID/joystick) that only has windows drivers. It came with a C/C++ SDK, so I can write code on the windows side for it. Unfortunately, the .dll that contains all the commands only works on windows.

I'd like to just publish the data from it to a roscore running on a linux machine. I don't need the core or tools or anything else.

What's the best way for me to do this? And what files will I need?

I've looked over the win_ros tutorials and the MinGW cross-compiling option (obviously) is not suitable.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11007/simple-publisher-from-windows?/) by [Geaelith](https://answers.ros.org/users/991/geaelith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-08-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're experimenting with a msvc ros_comms sdk. It's not official yet, but if you want to just quickly jump in and test, you can download the sdk zip from the files section on [win-ros-pkg](http://code.google.com/p/win-ros-pkg/downloads/list). More information on the roswki : [Installation/Windows](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Windows)

Compiling and linking against that sdk from an msvc project will let you run a publisher using one of the common msg stacks we've included (std_msgs/navi_msgs/geometry_msgs). If you need a custom msg format, simply generate your headers in linux and then copy the msg_gen/cpp/include/**pkg** directory into the sdk's include directory on your windows box.

The sdk is a debug, 32 bit msvc dll, built against the code in ros' electric release. It's also possible to build everything from scratch on windows using cmake, but that's a bit more difficult and still a bit volatile.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2011-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I had have a problems with Linux drivers for a measurement card that is well supported on Windows. So, first I tried the win-ros-pkg with the same result as you. Afterwards I discover the simple python workaround on

http://www.ros.org/wiki/cturtle/Installation/Windows

that needs only a transfer of a number of python files to the Windows PC. Afterwards you can implement a python publisher communicating your joystick data.

Best wishes

Poseidonius

---

Originally posted by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) with karma: 427 on 2011-08-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-08-28**:
Yep, this also works. We've done similarly with python.